# #DocuSignAPI: DocuSign Login using SOAP UI

Tags: soap, soapui, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API WSDL in my SOAP UI and trying to call a method but  getting the error *User_Authentication_Failed - Missing authentication header*

In some post seen that Security token need to to use but not getting the security token in docusign instead we have Integrator key value.

Please if someone  can provide the guidance here.

**My SOAP UI request is:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"> 
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
        <wsse:Username>haider@abcd.com</wsse:Username> 
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">HR123456</wsse:Password> 
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">iJwabpA/2j2ooh7deCAVcg==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2014-07-24T17:46:39.991Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken> 
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
        <wsu:Created>2014-07-24T17:46:19.730Z</wsu:Created> 
        <wsu:Expires>2014-07-24T17:56:19.730Z</wsu:Expires> 
     </wsu:Timestamp> 
  </wsse:Security> 
</soapenv:Header> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<ns:RequestPDF> 
<!--Optional:--> 
<ns:EnvelopeID>01f90b51-7cf4 -48a1-8946-2795fc970b77</ns:EnvelopeID> 
</ns:RequestPDF>
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Getting Response as:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
<soap:Header>
  <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action> 
  <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:6e9fbf02-7c18-4d65-bbfc-f828cf51bb57</wsa:MessageID> 
  <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:7e7b4a69-834f-4906-9b92-a16cc8f6d32b</wsa:RelatesTo> 
  <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To> 
  <wsse:Security> 
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-659010d2-c16b-479a-ae43-169846a7898c"> 
        <wsu:Created>2014-07-24T17:47:54Z</wsu:Created> 
        <wsu:Expires>2014-07-24T17:52:54Z</wsu:Expires> 
     </wsu:Timestamp> 
  </wsse:Security> 
</soap:Header> 
<soap:Body>  
<soap:Fault> 
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode> 
     <faultstring>User_Authentication_Failed - Missing authentication header</faultstring> 
     <detail/> 
  </soap:Fault> 
</soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What endpoint URL are you using? Also you're missing the integrator key in your SOAP Header.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the response. You mean i need to include Integrator Key with my User name? That was tried and didn't work. I am not getting What is the value i have to provide in UserNameToken wsu:ID=?? and the same for Timestamp wsu:Id="???". In few blogs saw some SecurityToken need to include but where we can see security token in Docusign? We have integrator Key, Account ID, User Login and Password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation below may be a better outline of using authentication headers and the endpoint URL's:

https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Introduction+Changes/Authentication.htm%3FTocPath%3DAuthentication%7C_____0

Below also outlines the above with Send On Behalf Of:

https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Introduction+Changes/Send On Behalf Of Functionality.htm%3FTocPath%3DAuthentication%7C_____2

Since the header type you choose also determines which endpoint URL you should use, below are examples for the demo environment:

HTTP = https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx

SOAP = https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx

Because you are utilizing SOAP, the correct endpoint would be the **api.asmx**.

In SOAP UI, you can:

- Select the endpoint drop down from the top
- **[edit current]**
- Populate the following URL:
  https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx

You would also need to add your Integrator Key as well inside the authentication. The integrator key should always be in brackets "[ ]" as well.My example below:

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>[INTEGRATOR KEY]DS USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[PASSWORD]</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SOAP UI you will add the header and value for the request. Select the header button at the footer of the page and select add. You will add your authentication header here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response , this one is DocusignAPI call in code. Want to know how to do this from SOAP UI.